# Is there a static address to a pointer on Mac OS?

Tags: c++, c, pointer, macos

Given the sample code below:

```
#include <iostream> 

struct Data {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

int main() {
    Data *d = new Data;
    d->a = 1337;
    d->b = 1338;
    d->c = 1339;

    std::cout << d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Printing out the address of the pointer `d` is never the same (which seems logical). But the pointer that points to the base of `d` is also never the same.

Is there a way to find a static address that is always the same and points to the base of `d`? Or do I need to do this with a signature scan?

The main purpose is to always have a pointer to the base of `d`, without disassembling it when I restarting the program.

Comment: Is the addition "on Mac OS" in your title and tags relevant? The observed behavior is common for almost all operating systems.

Comment: "Is there a way to find a static address ..." when live debugging? (I guess so; but maybe you might want to add the procedure you are using.)

Comment: *why* is the first observation "logical" but the other isn't?

Answer (score 1):

By declaring `d` inside main() it is a local scope variable, which exists on the stack and is therefore dynamic.

If you declare this pointer outside of main, it will be a global variable and it will have the same address every time, as long as there is know memory randomization provided as security measure of the OS.